# ¿por qué se me cambian los colores de un boton en mi pagina web en mac?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

estoy diseñando mi sitio web, y ya esta casi terminado, pero me pasa que al subir mi sito al servidor y visualizarlo en un navegador chrome en mac, mis botones de boostrap se me cambian de color a azul, a un color grisaseo, pero en windows en el mismo navegador de chrome se ven del color que los puse, ya intente poner los colores en rgb, exadecimal y en ingles, por ejemplo red, blue, e igual pasa que no se me ponen los colores en mac. ¿alguien sabe porque me pasa esto?

```html
<tr>
                <th scope="col">
                <form method="post" class="form-signin col-12">
                    <input type="search" name="name1" class="form-control" placeholder="id" required>
                    <div class="space-10"></div>
                    <button id="VER_FAC" class="btn btn-sm vervacantes btn-block" style="    margin-top: 5%; background-color: blue; color: white;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">Buscar archivos</button>
                  </form>
                  </th>
                <th scope="col">
                  <form method="post" class="form-signin col-12">
                    <input type="search" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Parte del nombre" required>
                    <div class="space-10"></div>
                    <button id="VER_FAC" class="btn btn-sm vervacantes btn-block" style="     margin-top: 5%;background-color: blue; color: white;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">Buscar archivos</button>
                  </form>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
                  <a href="files_fecha.php" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #3C3CFF; color: white;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"> Ordenar por fecha</a>
                </th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
                  <a href="files_estado.php" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: blue; color: white;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"> Ordenar por estado</a>
                </th>

                </th>
              </tr>
```

Comment: Has probado a poner un reset css en tu código?

Comment: no se como se hace eso. puedes explicarme por favor

Comment: Busca "reset css" y usa cualquiera de los que te ofrezcan las primeras páginas, luego haz el testeo y nos dices a ver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esto 'type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"' no va en una etiqueta a, tampoco los estilos van dentro de las etiquetas, para eso tienen clases e id y se pueden llamar.

```css
input{
border: 0; /* Cuando es un boton input se le quita el border o si no pasa lo mismo que te está pasando */
background-color: #ff0000;
color: #fff;
}
a{
background-color: #ff0000;
color: #fff;
}
button{
background-color: #ff0000;
color: #fff;
border: 0; /* Cuando es un boton BUTTON también se le quita el border o si no pasa lo mismo que te está pasando */
}

/* También puedes editarlos todos a la vez siempre y cuando tengan el mismo color */
input, a , button{
background-color: #ff0000;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Esto es un boton">

<a href="#">esto es un boton</a>

<button>esto es un boton</button>
```